# export selected actions with the fbx exporter

Tags: animation, export, file-format

Is there a way to only export select actions. As every time I export to unreal I have to delete a bunch of animations that are useful in blender but not something I need in unreal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add all actions you want to export as strips in the NLA, and then in FBX export settings, deselect `All Actions` and keep only `NLA Strips`. This should export only animation from NLA strips (i.e. actions).